# Why is Data not being passed through my Node REST API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-postgres

I have the following code.

routes/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const weeklyReportsController = require('../controllers/weeklyReportsController');

router.get('/weekly_reports', weeklyReportsController);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/weeklyReportsController.js:

```
const weeklyReportsService = require('../services/weeklyReportsService');

const weeklyReportsController = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const data = await weeklyReportsService;
        res.json({data})
        console.log('Weekly reports controller - success');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

module.exports = weeklyReportsController;
```

services/weeklyReportsService.js:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool

const pool = new Pool({connection data})
const weeklyReportsService = async () => {
    const res = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM reports', (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('Weekly reports service - success.');
        }
        return res.status(200).json(results.rows);
    });
};

module.exports = weeklyReportsService;
```

All I am returning by visiting localhost:8080/api/weekly_reports is an empty JSON object of {}. I tried adding some console.log() methods to my code to see what was triggering and what wasn't, and the log from my service is not being set off. I have spent a couple hours trying to dig through example codes, reading documentation, and honestly just looking blankly at my screen - I just can't figure out what I did wrong here.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you all for your time and if there is anything I can add for clarity, please don't hesitate to ask and I will provide it.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: The data is sitting in a Postgres database called reports with the table also called reports.

Comment: Can you try const data = await weeklyReportsService(); in your controllers/weeklyReportsController.js:?

Comment: @Sohan I am now getting the console to report so a step in the right direction! However, now I'm getting tossed "TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined." I checked the type of res and it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things wrong with your approach
Here's how you can achieve what you're trying to do:

controllers/weeklyReportsController.js:

```js
const weeklyReportsController = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const data = await weeklyReportsService();
        res.status(200).json({data})
        console.log('Weekly reports controller - success');
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message})
    }
};

module.exports = weeklyReportsController;
```

services/weeklyReportsService.js:

```js
const Pool = require('pg').Pool

const pool = new Pool({connection data})
const weeklyReportsService = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      pool.query('SELECT * FROM reports', (err, results) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        
        console.log('Weekly reports service - success.');
        resolve(results.rows)
      });
    })
};

module.exports = weeklyReportsService;
```

some links to help you get started: 
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64052334/2703813 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thank you so much! A lot to dig through here and I'll start going through it now. I appreciate your time.

Comment: "many things wrong", of which you list none, denotes more of criticism than a constructive answer.